# Maven exclusions specific version into fat jar

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am working in project where Springboot jar and Hive jar creating conflict becuase of duplicate versions

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78</version>
 </dependency>
```

Above hive jar is fat jar and coming with many duplicate dependancy ,in following example you can see two versions 2.6.0 and 3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78

Now if we want to add exclude

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>XX</artifactId>
                <groupId>YYY</groupId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
```

> Now i want to exclude only 2.6.0 version and keep 3  3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78
>   , is there any option where we can defined excluded jar version ?

```
[WARNING] 
Dependency convergence error for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:2.6.0 paths to dependency are:
+-com.syf.gemfire:jdbc-gemfire-dataloader-pcf:2.0.0
  +-org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78
    +-org.apache.hive:hive-common:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78
      +-com.github.joshelser:dropwizard-metrics-hadoop-metrics2-reporter:0.1.2
        +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.6.0
          +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:2.6.0
and
+-com.syf.gemfire:jdbc-gemfire-dataloader-pcf:2.0.0
  +-org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78
    +-org.apache.hive:hive-service:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78
      +-org.apache.hive:hive-llap-server:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78
        +-org.apache.hbase:hbase-hadoop2-compat:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78
          +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78
            +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78
              +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78
and
+-com.syf.gemfire:jdbc-gemfire-dataloader-pcf:2.0.0
  +-org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78
    +-org.apache.hive:hive-service:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78
      +-org.apache.hive:hive-llap-server:3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78
        +-org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78
          +-org.apache.hbase:hbase-http:2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78
            +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the dependency convergence errors, add entries to `<dependencyManagement>`, in which you specify the version you want like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78</version>
</dependency>
```

Then all transitively found versions are replaced by the one you specified an the conflict is gone.